# How to reshape input data correctly for training after it has been manipulated?

Tags: arrays, list, numpy, machine-learning, mnist

I am a beginner and I am working with the MNIST database and to gain experience, I tried manipulating the training data. Each digit image has also a set of 10 other digit images with corresponding labels in a random order.

Before: Image [5] -> Label [5]

Now: Image [5], Set:[[Image [0], Label [0]], [Image [5], Label [5]], ...] -> Label [5]

Shape **before** manipulation:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
Out[]:x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28)
```

Shape **after** manipulation:

```
print('x_train_new shape:', x_train_new.shape)
Out[]: x_train_new shape: (60000, 2)
```

Here is my manipulation process:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

### LOADING DATA ###
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

### RESHAPING PIXEL ARRAYS ###
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)

### CREATING SETS OF PIXEL ARRAYS AND LABELS FOR EACH IMAGE ###

## Random indexes ##
def get_random_train_indxs(group_value, count=1):
    train_indxs = np.arange(len(y_train), dtype=np.int32)
    train_group_indxs = train_indxs[y_train == group_value]
    return np.random.choice(train_group_indxs,count)

## Random indexes from labels ##
def get_random_indxs_from_y_train():
    listval = []
    for group_val in np.unique(y_train):
        i = get_random_train_indxs(group_val)
        listval.append(i)
    return listval
list_values_train = get_random_indxs_from_y_train()
random.shuffle(list_values_train, random.random)

## For every random index select a set of 10 ##
def array_and_label_for_x_train():
    digit_data = []
    labels = []
    for i in list_values_train:
        digit_array = x_train[i] #digit data (image array) is the data from index i
        label = y_train[i] #corresponding label
        digit_data.append(digit_array)
        labels.append(label)
    listtrain = list(zip(digit_data, labels))
    return listtrain

## Zip everything ##
def x_train_digit_with_set(digitset):
    x_train_var = []
    x_train_set = []
    for i in range(len(x_train)):
        digit_data = x_train[i] 
        label = y_train[i]
        print("Index of image receiving the set:", i), \
        x_train_var.append(digit_data)
        x_train_set.append(array_and_label_for_x_train())
        x_train_varset = np.asarray(list(zip(x_train_var, x_train_set)))
    return x_train_varset

x_train_new = x_train_digit_with_set(array_and_label_for_x_train())
print('x_train_new shape:', x_train_new.shape)
```

As you can see I am working with listappendings. But I think therein lies the mistake I am facing. 
When I am again reshaping the new data:

```
In []: x_train_new_res = x_train_new.reshape(x_train_new.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)

Out[]: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 120000 into shape (60000,28,28,1)
```

I think I am misunderstanding something and my approach is invalid. My question is: How to I correctly prepare my data for my machine? Does every new image in the set needs to be reshaped?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was the `x_train_varset = np.asarray(list(zip(x_train_var, x_train_set)))`. Zipping a list does not keep the data shape. Instead just create an empty `np.array([])` and `np.append` the data. This keeps the shape of the data.